# Retrieving unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes error socket python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, struct, python-sockets

I have the following code I am sending the result of intermediate predictions results from the client to server.

Client

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = 'localhost'
print('HOST IP:', host_ip)
port = 9999
socket_address = (host_ip, port)
server_socket.bind(socket_address)
server_socket.listen(5)
while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:', addr)
    if client_socket:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture("D:/testing.mp4")
        while (vid.isOpened()):
            img, frame = vid.read()
            image = img_to_array(frame)
            image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
            image = preprocess_input(image)
            preds = model.predict(image)
            a = pickle.dumps(preds)
            message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
        client_socket.sendall(message)
client_socket.close()
```

server

```
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host_ip = 'localhost'
    port = 9999
    client_socket.connect((host_ip, port))
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            packet = client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
            if not packet: break
            data += packet
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]
        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
```

While running the above code I am facing the below error

msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes

Thank you

Comment: The `if not packet: break` in your inner `while` loop is not breaking out far enough - if the connection was closed before you received even 8 bytes of data, then you must not continue with the outer `while`, as nothing in it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't sorted out normal end of connection. As mentioned in the comments, when the connection is closed by the client, you hit `if not packet: break` but that only breaks you out of the inner loop and you keep on trying to process a non-existent message. There is another bug in there where you don't clear out `data` per message.

When nesting loops, especially in communications where end of processing is discovered several steps down, I find it best to break the work into multiple functions with more narrowly defined roles. Here, you want to receive exactly one message at a time, build that into a python object and then use it. 3 functions for three things.

```
def do_the_things():
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host_ip = 'localhost'
    port = 9999
    client_socket.connect((host_ip, port))
    while True:
        frame = recv_frame(client_socket)
        if frame is None:
            break

payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
    
def recv_obj(client_socket):
    data = recvall(client_socket, payload_size)
    if len(data) < payload_size:
        if not data:
            # client closed after last message, assume all is well
            return None
        else:
            raise IOError("Truncated message")
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]
    remaining_data = recvall(client_socket, msg_size)
    if len(remaining_data) < msg_size:
        raise IOError("Truncated message")
    obj = pickle.loads(data + remaining_data)
    return obj

def recvall(sock, count):
    """Keep receiving up to `count` bytes, returning partial result
    if connection closed normally by remote."""
    data_bufs = []
    while count:
        data = sock.recv(count)
        if not data:
            break
        count -= len(data)
        data_bufs.append(data)
    return b"".join(data_bufs)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your wonderful suggestion and its really helpful @tdelaney. I just want to say that when I try to run your code I am the server closes the connection with the client not even receiving the data.

Comment: Is the client running okay? while (vid.isOpened()): ...perhaps its never open? Maybe an exception is raised? Sprinkle some prints in there that tell you what was sent. BTW, it looks like client_socket.close() should be indented to be inside the outer loop.

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, you are right while (vid.isOpened()) is not being opened . Thanks